# LightningchartJS open a menu on right click and added functionality

Tags: javascript, lightningchart

I am following this example

https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/interactive-examples/edit/lcjs-example-1400-histogramGaussian.html?isList=true

I need to know if there is a way to have the user right-click with the mouse to open a menu, for him to choose actions.

then,
I need to know if I can set an option that will change the color of that specific bar to red color for example.

[image]

Comment: Friendly reminder that LightningChart JS technical support is accessed through our customer portal https://lightningchart.com/js-charts/docs/services/support/

Stack Overflow exists for peer-to-peer support which is totally fine.

Comment: First I check the free help first ;) , to open a ticket I need to ask for approval after I used all resources